# write with Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working in an app for Android that uses BLE. I want to write inside a characteristic of the device Service that I am connected to.

My function is this:

```
public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled, String text) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }


    characteristic.setValue("7");

    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);


}
```

I do not why the value is not written inside the characteristic.
I followed the steps in this link:
[write with BLE](http://programminganswer.com/18642/android-4-3-ble-how-to-write-characteristic.html)

anyone knows why my code does not work?

Thank you very much.
Regards

P.D. apologies for my English.

Comment: what exactly happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending all morning at the computer trying different functions and forms, I found the solution thanks to a friend from work.
We have to convert the text to byte, then put that byte into a byte array and send. Fixed.

```
 byte pepe = (byte) Integer.parseInt(text);
 byte[] charLetra = new byte[1];

 charLetra[0] = pepe;

 LumChar.setValue(charLetra);
 boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(LumChar);
```

Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your `characteristic` accepts a `byte[]` value. Try setting the `characteristic` value with byte array by converting `String` parameter into `byte[]`. Your method should be like this:

```
public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                                            String text) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    byte[] data = hexStringToByteArray(text);

    characteristic.setValue(data);

    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}

private byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character
                .digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Also note that, `status` variable returns `true`, if the write operation was **initiated** successfully. So, in order to get write operation result status use `onCharacteristicWrite` [callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicWrite%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int%29) of `BluetoothGattCallback` and check the status in it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. The values that I want to send to the other device via bluetooth are numbers from 0 to 127. I use the following code: byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(Integer.valueOf(text)).array(); LumChar.setValue(bytes); boolean status = BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(LumChar); And this does not works because it does not write anything.